# Grouping a list into a nested list under a condition - Python

Tags: python, list, grouping

I have a list, `A = [1.10,1.11,1.12,1.21,1.22,1.48]`
and i would like to group the list `A` into a nested list `B` with the output:

```
B = [(1.10, 1.11, 1.12),
     (1.11, 1.12, 1.21),
     (1.12, 1.21, 1.22),
     (1.21, 1.22, 1.48)]
```

How could i produce B from A? I hope example is enough to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way that can be made to work with iterables that don't have length or can't be directly indexed:

```
from itertools import tee, islice, izip
A = [1.10,1.11,1.12,1.21,1.22,1.48]
groups = izip(*[islice(el, n, None) for n, el in enumerate(tee(A, 3))])
print list(groups)
# [(1.1, 1.11, 1.12), (1.11, 1.12, 1.21), (1.12, 1.21, 1.22), (1.21, 1.22, 1.48)]
```

Be wary to read up on how `itertools.tee` works in regards to caching values though.

Answer (score 5):

May be there is a prettier solution, but this works:

```
>>> A = [1.10,1.11,1.12,1.21,1.22,1.48]
>>> [A[i:i+3] for i in range(len(A) - 2)]
[[1.1, 1.11, 1.12], [1.11, 1.12, 1.21], [1.12, 1.21, 1.22], [1.21, 1.22, 1.48]]
```

Comment: Why not `range(len(A) - 2)` instead of the `if`?

Comment: You are assuming that the list above is already sorted. Just to make sure, I would add another `sort` statement in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

```
zip(A, A[1:], A[2:])
```

This makes it easy to wrap in a function and generalize to groups of N, and also makes it easy to turn into an iterator. (In Python 3.x, it already is; in 2.x, just use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip`.)

But the other solution isn't *that* much harder for either of those purposes; it's really a tossup.

Comment: I think we're close to the same lines here... Turning the above into `zip(*[A[n:] for n in range(3)])` is simple enough, and returns inner tuples instead of lists as the OP shows as output.

Comment: @JonClements: `zip` _already_ returns inner tuples rather than lists. But yes, that's how you generalize to groups of N.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that the currently highest voted answer creates a list of lists, not a list of tuples... ;)

Comment: @JonClements: Ah, I see. Anyway, the real benefit of your answer is in `tee` and `islice`, which means you only need constant temporary storage (well, O(N**2) where N is the group size, but I'm assuming N is a constant and << M) for an iterator, while mine (and most of the others) would require you to call `list` on it and waste O(M) temporary storage (where M is iterator length).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[tuple(A[i:i+3]) for i in xrange(len(A)-2)]

=> [(1.1, 1.11, 1.12),  (1.11, 1.12, 1.21),
    (1.12, 1.21, 1.22), (1.21, 1.22, 1.48)]
```